# $_POST not working when JQuery is included

Tags: php, html

So, I'm having an issue where my `$_POST` variable does not work whenever I have JQuery included on the page.

If I comment out the JQuery link it works fine. I have asked a similar question before, but did not get a full answer and have used a workaround which does not work with this page.

My full code is as followed:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['home-register-submit']))
      {
         echo '<script>alert("Works!");</script>';
      }
?>
       <div id='home-register'>
       <div id='home-register-title'><h4>Aanmelden</h4></div>
       <hr>
       <form method="POST">
       <label>Voornaam:</label> <div id='home-register-input'><input type="text" name='home-register-fname'></div><br />
       <label>Achternaam:</label> <div id='home-register-input'><input type='text' name='home-register-lname'></div><br />
       <label>Leeftijd:</label> <div id='home-register-input'><input type='' name='home-register-age'></div><br />
       <label>Telefoon:</label> <div id='home-register-input'><input type='tel' name='home-register-phone'></div><br />
       <label>Email:</label> <div id='home-register-input'><input type='email' name='home-register-email'></div><br />
       <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type='submit' name='home-register-submit'>Versturen</button>
       </form>
       </div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console? Since `$_POST` is PHP (and server-side) it shouldn't matter to jQuery (client-side).

Comment: There is no `GET` in your code. it's only `POST`, jquery or no jquery. So which `GET` is not working?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky is right. You are only checking for a POST parameter.

Comment: Your code is working here

Comment: *Stealth Edit Achievement Unlocked*

Comment: I just changed it, didn't see that @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: That's odd. Do you have any idea why it does not work on my end? @PHPhil

Comment: You don't have `action` attribute in your form element. Can it cause the problem?

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. Found out that there's a file called `clean-blog.min.js` blocks the page from using `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by excluding a file called `clean-blog.min.js` which apparently blocked my page from using `$_POST`.